# Constant repeating errors in console

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, windows, installation

Was just about to start learning Python in Blender, turned on the console and found the following message being constantly printed:

```
p_cache.gamepath_valid = os.path.exists(os.path.join(getGamePath(),"gameinf o
.txt"))
File "E:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\python\lib\ntpath.py",
line 108, in join
result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
File "E:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\python\lib\ntpath.py",
line 159, in splitdrive
if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Reverend Speed\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\
scripts\addons\io_scene_valvesource\__init__.py", line 105, in scene_load_post
game_path_changed(s,bpy.context)
File "C:\Users\Reverend Speed\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\
scripts\addons\io_scene_valvesource\__init__.py", line 139, in game_path_changed
```

Any clues? Had a problem with my E drive a while back, and while waiting for a solution I installed Blender (one of the 2.72 release candidates) to my C drive. When the final version of 2.72 came out, I installed that to C also.

Looking to fix this asap - was really anticipating getting stuck into Python and Blender tonight, but I won't be able to see any prints to console with this spamming constantly.

All the best,

--Rev

Comment: You could try to remove (or rename) the files from the old installations. It looks like blender tries to load things from your old directories.

Comment: Changed directory names and reloaded - no change. Then deleted the files (ie. sent them to the Recycle Bin) and reloaded - no change. I'm loath to delete the folders entirely in case it turns out I need to use the contents to fix the problem, though if you really think they need to be totally erased, I'll give it a shot. Oh, and thanks for the response!

Comment: Moving it to the Recycle Bin is definitely enough :). If that didn't help try the answer from Sybren below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I just uninstalled both installations, choosing to remove configs, autosaves and addons both times (though I saved my startup file to desktop beforehand). A fresh reinstall of 2.72 seems to have solved the problem: the console is no longer a flickering mass of errors.

My startup file contains all my standard measurement settings and a quick meander through User Preferences > Addons allowed me to reactivate my standard addons. Downloaded and installed MeshLint and I'm about ready to go. (Further addons can wait)

In hindsight, the problem was dumb and the solution obvious. =) Many thanks to TobiMarg and Sybren who gave me excellent advice in an attempt to save the structure - in the end I just razed it to the ground...!

Answer (score 2):

Although it's a drastic measure, you could erase the `%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender` directory. That'll make you loose all your settings (and possibly extra addons you installed), but also should reset any lingering references to the old installation directory.

Make sure you create a backup copy before doing this, though.